# Multi line log events for kubernetes pods

Tags: logging, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, multiline

How can I aggregate the log events to a single entry even though it is logged in multiple lines through application logger when docker is deployed to gcp kubernetes cluster.

For AWS we can use the date time format to identify the start of an event. What is the substitute in GCP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you need a dedicated solution to manage your logs really effectively.

One of the most popular solutions for aggregating/managing/sharing logs is [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/products), i.e. `ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana` or another version of similar stack, but with `Fluentd` instead of `Logstash`: `EFK stack`.

ELK Stack has a list of streamers or "[data shippers](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats)", which names are `beats`. One of them is `Filebeat`, which unsurprisingly works with files. In the nutshell it can read a file via `tail` method. So you can read any file.

The `Filebeat` [supports configuration options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html) to resolve your issue. They are:

```
multiline.pattern:
multiline.negate: 
multiline.match:
```

Generally, you should define regular expression which is describing the beginning of your lines unequivocally.

So, try this out. This stack supports different types of integration with the Kubernetes, e.g. in-cluster deployment and [autodiscover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover.html)